# Inlined functions have a non-inlined copy

Tags: c++, gcc, inline

In Agner Fog's [Optimizing C++ manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) he has a section "Inlined functions have a non-inlined copy" where he writes

> Function inlining has the complication that the same function may be called from another module. The compiler has to make a non-inlined copy of the inlined function for the sake of the possibility that the function is also called from another module. This non-inlined copy is dead code if no other modules call the function. This fragmentation of the code makes caching less efficient.

Let's make a test for this.

**foo.h**

```
inline double foo(double x) {
    return x;
}
```

**t1.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
double t1(double x) {
    return foo(x);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern double foo(double);

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", foo(3.14159));
}
```

compile with `g++ t1.cpp main.cpp` and it runs correctly.  If I do `g++ -S t1.cpp main.cpp` and look at the assembly I see that `main.s` calls a function defined in `t1.s`.  Doing `g++ -c main.cpp` and `g++ t1.cpp` and looking at the symbols with `nm` shows `U _Z3food` in `main.o` and `W _Z3food` in `t1.o`.  So it's clear that Agner's claim of there being a non-inlined copy is correct.

What about with `g++ -O1 t1.cpp main.cpp`? **This fails to compile due to `foo` being undefined.**  Doing `g++ -O1 t1.cpp` and `nm t1.o` shows that `_Z3food` has been stripped out.

Now I am confused.  I did not expect g++ to remove the non-inline copy with optimization enabled.

It seems that with optimization enabled `inline` is equivalent to `static inline`.  But without optimization `inline` means there is a non-inline copy generated.

Maybe GCC does not think I would ever want the non-inline copy.  But I can think of a case. Let's say  I wanted to create a library and in the library I want a function defined in multiple translation units (so that the compiler could inline the code for the function in each translation unit) but I also want an external module linking to my library to be able to call the function defined in the library. I would obviously need a non-inlined version of the function for this.

One suggestion Agner gives if I don't want the non-inline copy is to use `static inline`. But from this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876930/should-one-never-use-static-inline-function) I infer that this is only useful to show intent. So on the one hand it's clear it's more than just intent without using optimization since it makes a non-inline copy. But on the other had, with optimization it really only seems to show intent since the non-inline copy is stripped away. This is confusing.

My questions:

1. Is GCC correct in stripping away the non-inline copy with optimization enabled? In other words should there always be a non-inline copy if I don't use `static inline`?
2. If I want to be certain that there is not a non-inline copy should I use `static inline`?

---

I just realized that I could have misinterpreted Agner's statement.  When he says function inlinng he may be referering to the compiler inclining the code and not to the use of the `inline` keyword. In other words he could be referring to functions defined with `extern` and not with `inline` or `static`.

for example

```
//foo.cpp
int foo(int x) {
    return x;
}

float bar(int x) {
    return 1.0*foo(x);
}
```

and

```
//main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>    
extern float bar(int x);    
int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", bar(3));
}
```

compile with `gcc -O3 foo.cpp main.cpp` shows that `foo` was inline in `bar` but that a non-inlined copy of `foo` which is never used is in the binary.

Comment: I don't know what the standard says, but it makes sense for common cases. Usually inline/constexpr functions are defined in headers, so the case where it is declared, but not defined simply doesn't happen.

Comment: @kamikaze, can you be more specific. What it are you referring to in "it makes sense"...I don't know what you mean by declared but not defined. I am sorry my question is so long.

Comment: I think the point of this is that you should be able to create a pointer to an inline function (which will point to the noninlined version) and having a single instance of that noninlined version leads to less generated code in case multiple translation units want to have a pointer to the "inline function".

Comment: @Zboson Declared is when you have a prototype (i.e. the signature is known), like *double foo(double)*. The complete function with a body is defined.

Comment: @kamikaze, thanks, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard says that the full definition of an `inline` method needs to be visible in every translation unit that uses it:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly
>   the same definition in every case (3.2). [...] If a function with external linkage is
>   declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required.

(7.1.2/4 in N4140)

This does indeed make the example in your question ill-formed.

This rule also includes every TU from whatever external module is linking your library. They would also need the full definition in C++ code, e.g. by defining the function in a header. So a compiler can safely omit any kind of *"non-inlined copy"* if the current translation does not need it.

Concerning being certain the copy does not exist: The standard does not guarantee any optimization, so that is up to the compiler. Both with and without an additional `static` keyword.

Comment: Maybe I did not ask the right question then. Does this mean my code is dong something wrong? Should I not be calling `foo` from `main.cpp` if I did not define the inline function in `main.cpp` as well.  That's how I read your answer. My code example must be wrong.

Comment: @Zboson Yes, it is indeed wrong. I added a standard quote.

Comment: And Agner writes " This non-inlined copy is dead code if no other modules call the function." but why would any other module call this function unless it's defined in the same translation unit?

Comment: okay, thank you, I guess I expected you to point that out in your answer. I guess then I still don't know when to use `static inline` vs. only `inline`. I don't see how it will make a difference in practice if the code is correct.

Comment: @Zboson An `inline` function still has external linkage unless declared `static`. In this case, *"An inline function with external linkage shall have the same address in all
translation units."*

Comment: @Zboson For *"And Agner writes " This non-inlined copy is dead code if no other modules call the function." but why would any other module call this function unless it's defined in the same translation unit?"* I have no idea why he wrote that. I don't quite believe it.

Comment: Okay, I don't see how having external linkage vs static linkage for inline functions makes a difference in practice. When would it make a difference? I feel I need to ask a new question now.  Do you have a link showing where this makes a difference?

Comment: @Zboson There are special rules for static variables etc. in inline functions with external linkage, explained in 7.1.2 in N4140. If you have a question about that, I feel like you should ask a new, specific question.

Comment: Thanks, I agree I may need to ask a new question but I'll read up a bit first. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Zboson This might be interesting for you in case you didn't already read: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: @5gon12eder, thanks for the link. As I understand it C and C++ have important differences with `inline` so I have been mostly looking into C++ but maybe for `static inline` vs. `static` the main points are similar enough.

Comment: I always think C if I see `static` in front of a function because in C++, I'd expect an anonymous `namespace` be used instead. I don't think it makes any difference here, however.

Comment: I just realized the Agner's statement could be referring to `extern`functions (I mean ones decleared without `inline` or `static`).  I mean for example `int foo() {return 1;}` where `extern` is implicit. The compiler can still inline the code in the TU the function was defined but it will still create a non-inline copy incase another TU calls the function.

Comment: @Zboson Sounds plausible. LTO may or may not take care of that.