# Combining declare simd and inlining in a simd loop

Tags: fortran, openmp, vectorization, simd

I have been considering for a while when to inline or use `declare simd` in a simd loop. I came across this  [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091341/openmp-declare-simd-for-an-inline-function) which the OP has similar question, but the answer is rather not clear to me.

I have two questions:

1) Is it considered a bug to have both `declare simd(function_name)` and an inline directive like `!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES::FORCEINLINE(function_name)`.

2) How to know which one to use?

**A basic example**

```
!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES :: FORCEINLINE(call_insimd)
!$OMP DECLARE SIMD(call_insimd)
function call_insimd(a,b)  result(res)
implicit none 
real, intent(in) :: a,b 
real, intent(out):: res 
end function
```

In main  loop

```
do i = 1,10000 
!dir$ forceinline

  ar(i) = call_insimd(gf(i),df(i)) 

enddo
```

Comment: Unless you care about the possibility of multiple compilers which don't recognize both, there seems little reason to include both. Inline has potential advantages and disadvantages which you might ignore if you care only about simd.

Comment: when shall I use which. It seems that for simd loops there are two options with regards to function call, one is inlining and the other is declare simd - and I suppose sometimes it is better to use one over the other?

Comment: I generally do a !DIR ALIGN, and the compiler and compiler optimisation -02 usually shows with the vector report that the function is SIMD vectorised. Forcing it to be vectorised is also an option, but both ways get to the same result.